# The duplicate key value is (<NULL>, <NULL>)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

So I'm trying to migrate a table from MySQL to MSSQL (`sql server migration assistant MySQL`), but I get this error:

```
Migrating data...
Analyzing metadata...
Preparing table testreportingdebug.testcase...
Preparing data migration package...
Starting data migration Engine
Starting data migration...
The data migration engine is migrating table '`testreportingdebug`.`testcase`': > [SwMetrics].[testreportingdebug].[testcase], 8855 rows total
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'testcase$Unique'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'testreportingdebug.testcase'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>, <NULL>).
 Errors: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'testcase$Unique'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'testreportingdebug.testcase'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>, <NULL>).
Completing migration of table `testreportingdebug`.`testcase`...
Migration complete for table '`testreportingdebug`.`testcase`': > [SwMetrics].[testreportingdebug].[testcase], 0 rows migrated (Elapsed Time = 00:00:00:01:352).
Data migration operation has finished.
    0 table(s) successfully migrated.
    0 table(s) partially migrated.
    1 table(s) failed to migrate.
```

I've just copied three rows from my table, and this is what they look like:

```sql
'1',   'Pump# TimeToService',           NULL, NULL, 'A general test case comment ...', '0'
'2',   'Config.SlaveMinimumReplyDelay', NULL, NULL, NULL,                              '0'
'3',   'Config.RESERVED',               NULL, NULL, NULL,                              '0'
```

If you are wondering how the colons in the MySQL table is setup, here you go:

[image]

Is is because `right, left and comment` can be null?

**DDL of table**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `testcase` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TestCaseName` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Left` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Right` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comment` text,
  `Hidden` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Unique` (`Left`,`Right`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10580 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: MySQL does not consider NULL values as duplicates in UNIQUE constraint. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-unique *"A UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL."* Rather than SQL Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15#Unique *"UNIQUE constraints allow for the value NULL. However, as with any value participating in a UNIQUE constraint, only one null value is allowed per column"*.

Comment: @Akina I only have NULL values in columns which isn't set to be unique, so why does it fail?

Comment: Ask your models and migration codes about this.

Comment: Post DDL for the tables, not a fragment of a picture.

Comment: @SMor posted the DDL now

Comment: I've removed the incorrect tag *sql-server* from your qustion

Comment: @ZoharPeled why? I'm working on a `Microsoft SQL Server`

Comment: You have `UNIQUE KEY Unique (Left,Right)` and I see that these Left Right Columns are NULL.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Check out my answer :D

Comment: The code in the question will only throw errors if you attempted to run it on SQL Server. This is clearly MySql dialect and not TSql. If you're working with SQL Server, post the code that's relevant to SQL Server. Now I've read the question more carefully and I see you're attempting to migrate data from MySql to SQL Server. Sorry, I've missed that in my first read. I've added the sql-server tag back and added another tag for database-migration to prevent someone else to confuse like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Had to remove the Unique part, since their are only NULL.

```sql
ALTER TABLE `testreportingdebug`.`testcase` 
DROP INDEX `Unique`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the strict equivalent in SQL Server of your MySQL table you must create it like this :

```
CREATE TABLE testcase (
  id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  TestCaseName varchar(150),
  [Left] int,
  [Right] int,
  Comment VARCHAR(max),
  [Hidden] tinyint DEFAULT 0,
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX X_testcase_right_left 
   ON testcase ([Left], [Right])
   WHERE [Left] IS NOT NULL
     AND [Right] IS NOT NULL;
```

By the way, column names "Right", "left", "hidden" are SQL / MS SQL Server reserved words and should not be used at anytime for SQL identifiers (table name, colum name, proc name...)

The complete list can be obtain [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)